# CloudFront: path routing without trailing slash

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

There are two CloudFront Behaviros.
If URL path is `/articles/` or `/articles/123`, it will be routed to the server under ELB, but if `/articles`, it will be routed to S3.
I want to configure accesses to be routed to ELB even without trailing slash.

Can anyone give me some advice?
Should I write a CloudFront Function to redirect or modify the path pattern to solve this problem?

| Priority | Path pattern | Origin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | /articles/* | ELB |
| 1 | default(*) | S3 |

Comment: you can add a path pattern /articles to origin elb with a higher priority then /articles/*; I believe this would work; currently I dont really have a way to test it for you :)

Comment: Another way could be to add a redirect on articles (without trailing slash) on s3 to the slash equivalent  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#:~:text=example%201%3A%20redirect%20after%20renaming%20a%20key%20prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it in the following way: change Cloudfront path to `/articles*` instead of `/arcticles/*`.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a path pattern `/articles` to the same origin `ELB` with a higher priority then the one of `/articles/*`

Another way could be to add a [redirect on s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#:%7E:text=example%201%3A%20redirect%20after%20renaming%20a%20key%20prefix) on articles  to the slash equivalent